# fParity member of DCB structure always FALSE after a GetCommState

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port

With blood and tears, I just found out that the fParity member of a DCB structure is actively set to FALSE whenever you call GetCommState.

Is there a workaround for that (apart than explicitely setting dcb.fParity = 1; each time you need to call SetCommState)? Has anybody ever experienced this problem? Is there a MSDN article explaining this behaviour?

Here's a MCVE that reproduce the problem on my PC :

```
int main()
{
  HANDLE hComm;
  DCB dcb;

  // Replace COM1 by any COM port identifier on your PC
  hComm = CreateFile("COM1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    printf("Failed COM opening. Exit.");
    return -1;
  }

  FillMemory(&dcb, sizeof(dcb), 0);
  dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb);

  // Get the current DCB structure
  if (!GetCommState(hComm, &dcb))
  {
    printf("Failed GetCommState. Exit.");
    return -1;
  }

  // [Here, you may set any or all members of the dcb structure]
  // As suggested by chux and Hans Passant in a comment, try to set the parity to make the fParity value relevant.
  dcb.Parity = MARKPARITY;


  // This is the relevant bit :
  dcb.fParity = TRUE;

  // Set the new COM state.
  if (!SetCommState(hComm, &dcb))
  {
    printf("Failed SetCommState. Exit.");
    return -1;
  }

  // Read back the COM state (fParity should be TRUE)
  if (!GetCommState(hComm, &dcb))
  {
    printf("Failed GetCommState. Exit.");
    return -1;
  }

  printf("fParity = %d\n", dcb.fParity); // fParity value is 0.

  CloseHandle(hComm);
}
```

The only value not read back correctly after the GetCommState() is fParity.

Comment: Hard to guess what that is surprising.  GetCommState() just returns whatever config the previous port user used unless he carefully restored the config.  Which is not common.  Parity is not very commonly used and default is off.  You must **always** call SetCommState(), you cannot depend on a friendly other program to do it for you.  Unless you explicitly want the user to run such a program before yours, like MODE.

Comment: Maybe the field is "read-only" or at least needs to make sense with the field `Parity`.  Check that field too.  (Maybe if that is "NOPARITY", then parity checking is off.  IOWs, maybe you cannot have `fParity==1` and `Parity==NOPARITY`.  Various combinations of settings do not make sense or are available.

Comment: @HansPassant I am. Bear in mind that this is a MCVE showing how to reproduce the problem. Doing a GetCommState() and then setting the relevant members is the first of three methods for initially setting up a DCB structure (at least, according to MSDN). You can fill it with BuildCommDCB, but it doesn't change the fact that the fParity member won't be read back correctly.

Comment: I don't scroll down far enough.  Did you actually set the DCB.Parity field to a non-zero value?  This is otherwise up to the device driver, USB emulators are pretty shoddy so try another one.

Comment: @chux (and Hans) : Good catch. Indeed, in my original program, I set the parity to MARK, so I'll update the question to remove this possible confusion. I didn't want to get into too much useless details for my question, but basically I'm trying to read data from a device that has a 9 bit communication protocol and this can be emulated with a parity bit. It's working correctly, as long as I don't use a library which relies heavility on [Get/Set]CommState.

Comment: You cannot do this with parity, it will not be in sync with the actual transmission of the bytes.  Unless you add a great deal of sleep, making it entirely too slow.  These kind of protocols are used by vendors that want you to buy the hardware as well.  Resistance is futile.

Comment: @HansPassant : Like I said, this part is already working like a charm. The vendor in question recommends using the parity in a Windows program to read the ninth bit, and the technique works flawlessly if I hardcode the fParity member at TRUE each time I call SetCommState. My only problem really lies in my question : the fParity member is actively set to 0 after a call to GetCommState, and I can't find documentation about that behaviour, so it doesn't seem normal to me.

Comment: It does not work for reading data either.  You get the last programmed value, not the parity bit of the last received byte.  The vendor is just telling you a story.  Well, as long as it works like a charm then we can't argue with success :)   Good luck with it.

Comment: @HansPassant If you read one byte at a time, and don't use overlapped file IO, you can call ClearCommError() between each ReadFile() call, and check for a parity error. I'm sorry if you feel it doesn't work, and if it's a problem you've been having in the past, I'd be happy to provide you with sample code. But right now this discussion doesn't help me with my problem, which is an apparent bug in the GetCommState API. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `dcb.Parity = MARKPARITY;` may not be well supported,  It be interesting if code used `dcb.Parity = ODDPARITY;` and see it `dcb.fParity` then stays true.

Comment: @chux : Good catch again, but still, `dcb.fParity == 0` after the last GetCommState(). Just to be clear, the parity error reporting works correctly, as long as I have a single call to SetCommState() in my program (or as long as I hardcode setting fParity to 1 each time I call SetCommState). I found this problem because the library I'm using heavily relies on GetCommState and SetCommState, and the fParity member was only set once in the port opening function.

Comment: Suspect coding gremlins: Are _all_ the other fields as expected? The idea well here is going dry.

Comment: @chux : That's what I though at first. I still can't get myself to believe I found a "bug" in the oldest of the old features of Windows. And still... I tried `FillMemory(&dcb, sizeof(dcb), 0);` between the SetCommState and GetCommState call, and all the fields but fParity have the correct value. I even printed the structure values and compared them with Beyond Compare to be extra sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft about that and the semi-official answer is that yes, indeed, there's a bug with the `fParity` member of the DCB structure, as the value isn't read back properly by `GetCommState()`. The value of `fParity` will always be false (even though the documentation says that the default value is true).

They also informed me that the `fParity` flag isn't checked at all by the driver, and that parity errors are reported (or not) based on the `Parity` flag setting.

That last bit of information stumped me a little bit, as the MSDN page about DCB specifically indicates that another member of the structure, `fErrorChar`, doesn't take effect unless `fParity` is true. I never got a satisfactory explanation about the behavior of `fErrorChar`.

I suspect the MSDN documentation to be misleading about the COM driver's capabilities, which embarrasses Microsoft. And anyway, this can't be fixed unless a host of legacy applications suddenly face backward compatibility issues.

Answer (score -1):

from your code above it looks like you are communicating using mark and space parity scheme. when you called `GetCommState`, what did you get in `Parity` field.

since `GetCommState` is not returning `fParity` as `True`, it might help calling `ClearCommError` and checking if second out argument `COMSTAT` has `CE_RXPARITY`. not sure in your case will it work or not but when calling `ClearCommError` after receiving some data on port, it should work.

Comment: I'm not even talking about receiving data on the port. You're too far ahead. The problem happens when trying to set the initial settings of the communication device. This problem happens even if no device is connected to the computer. It's a matter of initialization, not communication.